# How does addToSet determine a duplicate?

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a document that contains an array named `Months`. Each element in the array has a int field indicating which month & year it refers to (yyyyMM), e.g. 201612, 201701, etc.

Each such element also contains additional fields, pertaining to that particular month. e.g. int numOfItems, string Country, etc.

Now, assuming I have such document with only 2 elements in the array:

```
Months[0].month == 201612
Months[1].month == 201701
```

Then, I call **addToSet** with `Months[1].month` == 201701.

How does [addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) determine whether this is a duplicate or not?

Does it inspect and compare **all** sub-elements  of `Months[1]` to do that? Does it only inspect the index of the element in the Months array?

Comment: It does an object comparison

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks! To clarify your answer, you mean it inspects and compares all sub-elements of the element to add, right?

Comment: Indeed, so if you want to compare by a single property or something you need to add an additional condition to your query

Comment: Yes, I do want to limit the compare to array index (and perhaps the value of the month at that index). How do I do that? Could this be done through the [UpdateDefinition](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateDefinition_1.htm?_ga=1.106881984.2124943975.1481447453)?

Answer (score 5):

This is directly from MongoDB.

[MongoDB - AddToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

> If the value is a document, MongoDB determines that the document is a duplicate if an existing document in the array matches the to-be-added document exactly; i.e. the existing document has the exact same fields and values and the fields are in the same order. As such, field order matters and you cannot specify that MongoDB compare only a subset of the fields in the document to determine whether the document is a duplicate of an existing array element.